# Conditions for Mapper.Map to iList

Tags: c#, automapper

I have the following structure set up to Map an iList to a collection. At one point, removed items were simply deleted from the database, but now they are "marked" as deleted (flag) which means the deleted items now need to be filtered in the mapping. I have used the: 
.ForAllMembers(opt => opt.Condition(src => !src.Deleted.Equals(true))
syntax for the db to object mappings which works fine, however, I can't figure out how to include the filter when the object is a list. The code is as follows:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<IList<DbItem>, Collection>()
     .ConstructUsing(
        (IList<DbItem> src) =>
             src != null 
                 ? new AuthorizedContactCollection(Mapper.Map(src), *xxx*)
                 : new AuthorizedContactCollection())
     .Ignore(dest => dest.IsSynchronized);
```

My suspicion is that the filter should go where the *xxx* is, but I can't figure out the syntax...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got IT.
     Mapper.Map>(src.Where(x => x.Deleted.Equals(true))))

Hopefully this helps someone else at some point!

Answer (score 0):

Got the syntax, but it isn't filtering the value out for some reason...

src != null 
                            ? new AuthorizedContactCollection(Mapper.Map>(src).Where(x => !x.Deleted.Equals(true)))
                            : new AuthorizedContactCollection())

the object isn't being filtered out...